# Ruby—subclasses using instance variables of the parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

```
class A
  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
  end

  def test
    puts @var
  end
end

a = A.new('hello')

b = B.new
b.test
```

This code doesn't work, because `b` inherits from `A` but not `a`.

In Ruby (or Rails), how do I get this kind of behavior? Inheritance is useful for sharing methods, can it also share data?

---

UPDATE

This question is a bit confusing, so I will try to clarify.

I want instances of `B` to inherit not only from the class `A`, but also from an instance of `A`. That way, I could do something like this:

```
a1 = A.new('one')
a2 = A.new('two')
b1 = a1.B.new # not ruby syntax, but this is why I'm asking the question
b2 = a2.B.new
b3 = a2.B.new

b3.test
#=> 'two'
b2.test
#=> 'two'
b1.test
#=> 'one'
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve an object relationship where I can access a parent's data as well as methods

Comment: After your edition: It does not work not because instance variables are somehow "not shared" (whatever it means), but because you overwrote method `initialize` in `A` class so now it doesn't set `@var` instance variable. What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by trying to achieve 'parent's data'? Instance variables only live on instances, not on classes (well they do, but it's a different case then).

Comment: What should happen when the variable `@var` is updated in the context of `b`? Should `a.test` change then too?

Comment: @spickermann The idea is that `@var` belongs to `a`, but `a`'s child `b` can access it. Kind of like a global variable for all children of `a`

Comment: @Mirror318 as I wrote, instance variables live on instances, so if you define it on `b`, it will be defined on `b`. You just don't do this in your example, so you shouldn't expect this to 'work'.

Comment: I have updated the question to (hopefully) clarify what I'm trying to do

Comment: Use composition, not inheritance if you want to depene on a single instance. See my update below.

Comment: It's unclear *why* you want to do this--this isn't how OOP works in Ruby (and most other OOP languages). It sounds like you want a mix of "classical" and prototypal inheritance. While there a variety of hacks it might be better to fit the problem to the language.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm curious to see how it can be done regardless of whether it _should_ be done. However, the example I have is that a few different classes are reading the same data for their methods. So instead of redundant db queries, I'd like the parent instance to do the query once, and have the children read from it.

Comment: @Mirror318 That doesn't really explain why you want to do it like *this*. So far it sounds like simple composition is more what you want, or a factory off of `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to achieve your goal would be to use the little known [SimpleDelegator](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) class:

```
class A
  attr_reader :var

  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
  end
end

require 'delegate'

class B < SimpleDelegator
  def test
    puts var
  end
end

a1 = A.new('one')
a2 = A.new('two')
b1 = B.new(a1)
b1 = B.new(a1)
b2 = B.new(a2)
b3 = B.new(a2)

b3.test
#=> 'two'
b2.test
#=> 'two'
b1.test
#=> 'one'
```

This [blog article](https://blog.lelonek.me/how-to-delegate-methods-in-ruby-a7a71b077d99) ("5 ways of forwarding your work to some other object in Ruby") might be of interest to you.

Comment: This is great. One problem is that it will only delegate public methods from the parent class (so it can't do e.g. private memoization methods). Do you know if there's a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a class variable then:

```
class A
  def initialize(var)
    @@var = var
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
  end

  def test
    puts @@var
  end
end

a = A.new('hello')

b = B.new
b.test
#=> 'hello'
```

Comment: This is in the right direction, but I'm looking for a variable scoped to instances of `A`. So if there's `a1 = A.new('one')` and `a2 = A.new('two')`, then all children of `a1` would see `@var == 'one'` and all children of `a2` would see `@var == 'two'`

Comment: Classes inherit from classes. But `a1` and `a2` are instances. You cannot inherit a class from an instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using 'inheritance' as you described, because there's no such thing as inheritance from an instance in Ruby world. But, having said that, you can do some hacking to actually get what (I guess) you need, using `delegate` (you can do it, because, as you wrote, you're using Rails):

```
class A
  attr_reader :var # here, you set method to get `@var` value
  # ...
end

class B < A
  delegate :var, to: :a # here, you're setting delegator

  attr_reader :a # It's used by line above

  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def test
    puts var
  end
end
a1 = A.new('one')
a2 = A.new('two')
b1 = B.new(a1)
b2 = B.new(a2)
b3 = B.new(a2)
b1.test
# one
b2.test
# two
b3.test
# two
```

Keep in mind though it's a solution written from scratch, as there's no 'syntatic' way to do this, as there's no inheritance from instances in Ruby world.

Answer (score 0):

Your code raises error:

```
b = B.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
from (pry):14:in `initialize'
```

`B` inherits the constructor and requires an argument in the intitialization.

See below:

```
b = B.new("hello")
# => #<B:0x0000555b8b8c20d0 @var="hello">
b.test
# hello
# => nil
```

As you can see, the ivar is inherited.

EDIT

In this case, you'd better use composition than inheritance:

```
class A
  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
  end
  attr_accessor :var
end

class B < A
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def test
    puts var
  end

  def var
    a.var
  end

  def var=(var)
    a.var=(var)
  end
end

# or with delegation
class C < A
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
  delegate :var, :var=, to: :a

  def test
    puts var
  end
end
```

Comment: Right, I just updated the code example. Bugs aside, the question is can I have an object that is a child of an instance of it's parent class, accessing data?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to all `B` instances do inherit data from some specific `A` instance?

Answer (score 0):

One highly unrecommended way to achieve this would be to move the inheritance chain into a dynamic module, eg.

```
class InheritableState < Module
  def initialize(key)
    var_name = "@@#{key}_state".to_sym

    define_method :state do 
      return self.class.class_variable_get(var_name) if self.class.class_variable_defined?(var_name)
      self.class.class_variable_set(var_name, nil)
    end

    define_method :state= do |val|
      self.class.class_variable_set(var_name, val)
    end
  end
end

class A
end

> a, b, c = A.new, A.new, A.new
 => [#<A:0x00007fb691944338>, #<A:0x00007fb691944310>, #<A:0x00007fb6919442e8>]
> a.extend(InheritableState.new("abc")); b.extend(InheritableState.new("abc")); c.extend(InheritableState.new("def"));
 => #<A:0x00007fb6919442e8>
> [a.state, b.state, c.state]
 => [nil, nil, nil]
> a.state = "abc"
 => "abc"
> [a.state, b.state, c.state]
 => ["abc", "abc", nil]
```